# How strong, resistant and fast can a (humanoid) living being be?

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

How fast could run a humanoid being, how much damage could resist, how much weight could lift, how strong could hit, under the indicated evolutionary conditions? is there a limit? I have always thought that in real life the limit is more about the composition and energy source of the living, so, following a"realistic" evolution (idk, maybe like a Gorilla with leathery/Bone armor shell, but i really hope my creature could be stronger than that)

This humanoid being is about 2 meters tall, although it really doesn't matter if a lower height is more useful, while still in human height standards

Comment: Asking what the maximum a human could be made using evolution and the maximum a human can be made using basically bio-engineering are two separate questions. Which one do you want the answer for?

Comment: @Halfthawed You're right, sorry, I will edit the question

Comment: Arguably the current human is the end result of a 'realistic' evolution - once we received the intelligence to build things faster than nature (i.e. building weapons and armor as opposed to evolving them), than evolution lost it's main hold on humanity.

Comment: Please note that in engineering there are *always* tradeoffs. For example, it's easy to evolve a humanoid creature which is much stronger than humans (for example, our close cousins the chimpanzees and the gorillas are *very much* stronger than us), but the downside is that the creature's endurance would be much lower; humans took the path emphasizing endurance, and thus our muscles have reduced mass and strength so that our lungs can supply enough oxygen to keep them in aerobic mode when running or working with moderate effort; our cousins took the path to emphasize strength over endurance.

Comment: Seems like if you want some paragon values to work with, the Olympics will be on TV soon. Let's see -- speed, strength, endurance. All that's missing is resistance to injury...that one is not great. We tend to use our brains to manage risk and avoid the injury instead.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there are several limitations a human body has in terms of shock absorbtion:

1. Materials of our body have limits
2. Brain is limited to the shock it may absorb
3. Eyes also have limited shock absorption

Lets look at the points in more detail:

1. The materials our body consists of, are actually a result of materials that are abundant and easy to produce. If we replace our bones with titan than we have more resistance to shock.
2. SSD could sustain about 1500 g and humans could only sustain 9 g. It is theoretically possible to run our brain on the same technology microcontroller use and then our brain will be much more more shock resistant.
3. Eyes could be replaced with cameras that could sustain 150 g.

So under specific conditions humanoids could develop their parts from materials and technologies that are more resistant to shock. You just need to have the materials widely available and have a technology to use these materials to build the body. Most of our body consists of water which does not allow us to exist in space because water boils in space. The same way our bones are made of calcium and could be made of titan. But titan is too rare to constantly rely on it to build a big part of our body.

Comment: Your biological creature will start resembling a machine, with titanium or steel bones, carbon nanotube muscles, and a high octane fuel source. If you imagine the strongest, fastest theoretical robot you could ever produce, you could have something that is bullet resistant, can break weightlifting records multiple times over, and run somewhat faster than a cheetah if it has the proper body. High handwavium involved as to how the environment to support this exists.

Answer (score 1):

For real humans, the strongest punch measured around 1300Lbs of force (about 28500N). The fastest run is over 28mph (about 45km/h), with it predicted that the maximum running speed allowed by human biology is around 64km/h (40mph).

Numbers seem harder to pin down for Gorillas, but it seems like 10 times the strength of a human is possible.

Durability is harder to predict. Odds are that the muscle mass necessary to get to the level of a gorilla with pro boxer attacks will add durability to the relevant areas of the body, but I'm not sure what the maximum head / neck protection allowed by biology could be. I'm also not sure how running speed would be affected.

So a lower bound on strength is 3-30kn of strike force, and 64km/h of running speed. The maximum is probably higher, ignoring tradeoffs at the extremes.